# How to make a new activity when someone clicks on the hardware button menu settings

Tags: java, android, menu, onclick, hardware

I have a project and if someone clicks on the hardware button menu, three different options appear:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_information"
    android:title="@string/action_information"/>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_impressum"
    android:title="@string/action_impressum"/>
```

I created a setting, information and impressum activity. Now it should be possible to show them if someone clicks on the appropriate menu subitem. But I have no glue how to do that. I know, how to click a button and show a new activity:

```
View button = findViewById(R.id.button_pong);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                        PongActivity.class);
                startActivity(startActivity);
            }
        });
```

is it similar with the hardware button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Activity, override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater mnuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    mnuInflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu); // your_menu IS THE MENU XML YOU HAVE CREATED
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And to run functions (in your case, start an Activity) override the `onOptionsItemSelected()`. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_settings:

        // DO SOMETHING HERE

        return true;

    case R.id.action_information:

        // DO SOMETHING HERE

        return true;

    case R.id.action_impressum:

        // DO SOMETHING HERE

        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If, for example, you need to start the `PongActivity` when the user selects the `action_settings` in your Menu XML, then that block would look like this: (*this code will go in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` as illustrated above*)

```
case R.id.action_settings:
    // START THE PongActivity
    Intent startActivity = new Intent(this, PongActivity.class);
    startActivity(startActivity);

    return true;
```

Comment: Why is overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu` necessary?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: Because you want to show your own menu in an Activity / Fragment. Without, overriding the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, you cannot plug in your own Menu. Think of it as overriding the `onCreate`. To show your own layout / UI, that override is necessary. The same with when you need to show your own Menu. That being said, if you don't override the `onCreateOptionsMenu` there is no default Menu that will be shown. There simply wont be a Menu displayed / shown.

Answer (score 1):

Read the official [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).  Look for the bit on "Handling Click Events."

As you have already guessed, the mechanism works vaguely like onClick handler, but there's a separate method called onOptionsItemSelected() with a big switch statement inside with a case for each menu item defined by your activity.

Your startActivity(intent) code would go into the appropriate case.